# Useful Commandline Commands on Unix

Tags: linux, unix, command-line-interface, command

As there is a [windows version](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-commandline-commands-on-windows) of this question, I decided to open a community wiki for the same question under unix, linux, and the like.

I'll be updating this list with the answers:

- bash: exec 3<> /dev/tcp/localhost/80  # Redirect to port 80 of localhost
- find: search for files in a directory hierarchy
- htop: interactive process viewer, similar to top
- xargs: build and execute command lines from standard input
- tmux: detachable, re-attachable command line sessions
- apropo: find relevant man pages
- vmstat: See the state of your system

Websites:

- commandlinefu.com
- serverfault.com

Keyboard shortcuts:
 - Ctrl T (BSD specific): send SIGINFO to a running program
 - Magic SesRq key (Linux specific): en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key

Comment: See @Andrew Hodgson's response.

Comment: Yeah, actually I see it.

Answer (score 8):

Try [commandlinefu.com](http://www.commandlinefu.com/).

Answer (score 7):

'screen' - allows for detachable, re-attachable command line sessions. Made extra shiny with screen-profiles (default in Ubuntu 9.04), and byobu in 10.04

Answer (score 3):

Slight dupe:

[Hidden Features of Linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/2817/hidden-features-of-linux)

[Hidden Features of Linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/2817/hidden-features-of-linux)

Comment: yeah, I didn't find it

Answer (score 2):

`find`. Extremely useful in combination with `xargs`.

Comment: But also on its own.

Comment: The use of `-exec` in `find` makes `xargs` useless most of the time.

Answer (score 2):

- [Shell-fu.org](http://www.shell-fu.org/)
- [Command Line Interface Ninja Howto](http://www.involution.com/clguide.html)

Answer (score 2):

Using 'ack' as a replacement for grep/find+xargs+grep: www.betterthangrep.com

Answer (score 2):

reset

for when you accidentally cat a binary file :-)

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not commands per se, but I've found knowing that you can set bash to use emacs or vi-style shortcuts to navigate the prompt to be especially useful. Ctrl+A to move to the beginning of the line, Ctrl+E to move to the end of the line, and all the others (c.f. http://www.hypexr.org/bash_tutorial.php).

Comment: I know that bash uses emacs style by default, but is it actually possible to have it use vi commands? I'd love that, but I'm not sure how it'd work. (Edit: I just realized how old this is....but ah well. Legit question.)

Answer (score 0):

`ls` - list directory contents.
`ls /bin` `ls /usr/bin` `ls /usr/local/bin` : See what other toys you can play with

Answer (score 0):

`pushd, popd` - push directory, pop directory

`cd` - without any parameters will take you back to your home directory.

`history` - gives a list of all the previous command combinations that were run.  You can grep this list if you're looking for something specific.  And then use `!n` to recall it.